# Vue 3 на сервере разработки при переходе по адресу выдаёт ошибку cannot get /адрес

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue3, vue-cli

Имею вот такую ссылку:

```
  <li
    class="header-list__item" 
  >
       <a href="/roadmap">
            <div class="header-nav-link__img roadmap-header-btn"></div>
            <p class="header-nav-link__text">
                 Дорога<br>прогресса
            </p>
      </a>
  </li>
```

Вот router.js:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'; 

// Компоненты
import MainLayout from '@/pages/MainLayout';

import Roadmap from '@/components/roadmap/Roadmap';
import MainPage from '@/pages/MainPage';

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'main',
            component: MainLayout,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/',
                    name: 'main',
                    component: MainPage
                },
                {
                    path: '/roadmap',
                    name: 'roadmap',
                    component: Roadmap
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

Вчера всё работало нормально, но когда сегодня я ничего не меняя развернул сервер с помощью:

```
npm run serve
```

То при переходе по ссылке получил белую страницу вот с такой ошибкой:

```
Cannot GET /roadmap
```

В то время как в production версии всё работает отлично:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста!!! Не знаю что делать, повторно скажу, что вчера всё работало отлично, а сегодня я ничего не менял. А, точно, проект генерировал с помощью vue-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему вы используйте тег `<a>`, а не `<router-link>`?

Как я понял, вполне возможно что у вас сервер настроен как то не правильно. На проде у вас стоит какой-нибудь nginx, который все запросы проксирует на `/`. Скорее всего, именно по этому пути у вас лежит приложение. А далее уже `vue-router` берет на себя маршрутизацию. Если вы используете тег `<a>`, то при переходе по ссылкам, у вас страница перезагружается. На проде все норм, потому что там сервер настроен правильно, а на локальной машине по пути `/roadmap` у вас ничего нет.

Во-первых, вам нужно на локальной машине перед vue поставить какой-нибудь сервер, который все запросы будет перенаправлять на корень `/`. Или покопайтесь в настройках `vue-cli`, на сколько я знаю, с ним уже какойто сервер в коробке идет.

Во-вторых, вместо `<a>` используйте `<router-link>`. Так `vue-router` сможет перехватить нажатие на ссылку, и у вас сайт не будет перезагружаться, при клике на нее.

Тут подробнее про `<router-link>` https://v3.router.vuejs.org/ru/api/#router-link

Comment: Спасибо большое) Да, оказывается я установил publicPath : "./", когда поставил просто "/", то всё заработало, а тег <a> я использую специально, чтобы при переходе происходила перезагрузка, на данный момент это требуется в проекте. Мы только переходим на vue с jquery, поэтому нужна перезагрузка, так устроены старые модули, которые подгружаем с помощью ajax. В дальнейшем будем полностью переписывать на vue, тогда и будем использовать уже <router-link>